# CGBlog (cmsms) reduce number of results per page

Tags: cmsmadesimple

When using CGBlog summary page it outputs 25 results per page. Is it possible to increase or reduce this?

Also im not sure if it outputs 25 be default or if it is somehow set somewhere else.

Here is my summary page code.

```
<!-- Start CGBlog Display Template -->
{if isset($error)}{cgerror}{$error}{/cgerror}{/if}

{if $pagecount > 1}
  <p>
    {if $pagenumber > 1}
      <a href="{$firsturl}">{$mod->Lang('firstpage')}</a>&nbsp;
      <a href="{$prevurl}">{$mod->Lang('prevpage')}</a>&nbsp;
    {/if}
    {$mod->Lang('prompt_page')  }&nbsp;{$pagenumber}&nbsp;{$oftext}&nbsp;{$pagecount}
    {if $pagenumber < $pagecount}
      &nbsp;<a href="{$nexturl}">{$mod->Lang('nextpage')}</a>
      &nbsp;<a href="{$lasturl}">{$mod->Lang('lastpage')}</a>
    {/if}
  </p>
{/if}

{foreach from=$items item=entry}
<div class="CGBlogSummary">

{if $entry->postdate}
    <div class="CGBlogSummaryPostdate">
        <strong>{$entry->postdate|cms_date_format:"F j, Y"}</strong>
    </div>
{/if}

{if $entry->categories}
<div class="CGBlogSummaryCategory">
{strip}<strong>{$category_label}&nbsp;</strong>
 {foreach from=$entry->categories item='category'}
   {$category.name}&nbsp;
 {/foreach}
{/strip}
</div>

{/if}
<div class="CGBlogSummaryLink">
<!--<strong>Category:</strong> {$category.name}<br>-->
<strong><a href="{$entry->detail_url}" title="{$entry->title|escape:htmlall}">{$entry->title|escape}</a></strong>

</div>



<!--{if $entry->author}
    <div class="CGBlogSummaryAuthor">
        {$author_label} {$entry->author}
    </div>
{/if}-->

{if $entry->summary}
    <div class="CGBlogSummarySummary">
        {eval var=$entry->summary}
    </div>

{else if $entry->content}

    <div class="CGBlogSummaryContent">
        {eval var=$entry->content}
    </div>
{/if}

{if isset($entry->extra)}
    <div class="CGBlogSummaryExtra">
        {eval var=$entry->extra}
    {* {cms_module module='Uploads' mode='simpleurl' upload_id=$entry->extravalue} *}
    </div>
{/if}
<!--{if isset($entry->fields)}
  {foreach from=$entry->fields item='field'}
     <div class="CGBlogSummaryField">
        {if $field->type == 'file'}
          <img src="{$entry->file_location}/{$field->value}"/>
        {else}
          {$field->name}:&nbsp;{eval var=$field->value}
        {/if}
     </div>
  {/foreach}
{/if}-->

<br />
</div>
{/foreach}
<!-- End CGBlog Display Template -->
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look in:
Content > Calguys Blog Module > Options tab > Default page limit